# Component one grid layout flickers within windowsformshost within WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Layout of componentone grid moves and again sits in place while i scroll. It leaves a flickering effect as if the grid comes over the groupbox header and again comes back when i leave the scroll. What may be issue. I have tried many solutions.

```
<Grid>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
<Groupbox>
<WindowsFormsHost>
<FlexGrid> </FlexGrid>
</WindowsFormsHost>
</Groupbox>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Plz post your code.. & what U tried..